# React hook form useFormContext generating "argument of type 'string | undefined'" error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to react and I am using `react-hook-form` `useFormContext`and it is generating the following error, `Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.` and I am not sure why. My code is the following,

`const mapFields = new Map([['d1', '1'], ['d1', '2'], ['d3', '3']]); register(mapFields.get('d1'), { required: true })`

I tried passing a function into register instead of a map and it worked fine so not sure why this is occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the non-null assertion operator (`!`) to tell TypeScript that the value cannot be undefined.

```js
register(mapFields.get('d1')!, { required: true })
```

Comment: yep that fixed it. Can you elaborate why that is?

Comment: @user21305522 TypeScript doesn't know if the key exists on the `Map` or not. Thus the type is `string | undefined`.